# Change text format used for text field when displayed in a view?

Tags: 7, views, media, input-formats

I have a content type with a text field that may contain a token from the Media module (that WYSYWIG inserts). This token is typically transformed into HTML by enabling a specific filter for the text format used.

However, I want to create a view for nodes of this type that just **strips out the media token entirely**. This allows me to show the content w/o any images or captions.

Initially, I thought I could add my own field formatter using [hook_field_formatter_info](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_info/7) and [hook_field_formatter_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_view/7), strip out the token right in the formatter, and then use that formatter when rendering the field in the view (views lets you select a formatter, like Default, Trimmed, etc).

The problem there is that by the time `hook_field_formatter_view` is called, the `safe_value` for the field is already computed and text has already been run through the input filter (so the token has been transformed).

I wonder if there's a way I can create a new text format that doesn't include the Media token filter and somehow tell views to render the field using that, but it doesn't appear like I can.

Answer (score 0):

I found an issue concerning something similar to you question on Drupal.org

https://www.drupal.org/node/1113088

There is some module code provided which may be useful to you.

The module looks like it uses a field formatter.  Instead of taking out the media tags, it aims to strip out the resulting html tags.

```
$pattern = array('/<div class="media[^"]+">.+<\/div>/im', '/<p><\/p>/im', '/<p[^>]+><\/p>/im');
  $item['safe_value'] = preg_replace($pattern, '', $item['safe_value']);
```

Comment: Thanks, I took a look. Unfortunately there is no real solution there other than stripping the HTML out, which I don't want to get involved in.